# How to rotate the X axis Label in Odoo V9 Graph view

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-view

In OpenERP 7, We have provision to rotate the label in X-axis by altering the graph.js,

```
options_line: function (data) {
        xaxis : {
            labelsAngle: 45,
            ticks: this.orientation ? false : data.ticks
        }
```

But in ODOO V9, web_diagram ---> js -----> graph.js,
There is no provision to get the line graph and rotate the axis

Comment: Which label do you wish to rotate? All of them? Show us with a screenshot

Comment: Thanks for the concern George, I rotate the label in graph view.